# Is there a hotkey in VS code to jump to the content space of the next element of html?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, hotkeys

I have some html like:

```
<section>
   <h5>|</h5>
   <h3></h3>
   <p></p>
</section>
```

where the vertical line | is the cursor. Is there a hotkey to make it jump from between one set of tags to the next?

So, from <h5>|</h5> to <h3>|</h3> and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) and the command `moveby.regex`

Define the following key binding:

```
  {
    "key": "shift+f7",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "regex": "<(?!/)[^>]+>",
      "properties": ["next", "end"]
    }
  }
```